# Advantage of returning boxed primitive values from library function

Tags: java, primitive-types, jedis, boxing, lettuce

### Context

I am looking at a couple of Java Redis clients like Lettuce and Jedis. I see that both libraries have defined their methods to return boxed primitive types rather than straight primitives.

For example, `sadd()` returns `Long` rather than just `long`.
https://lettuce.io/lettuce-4/release/api/com/lambdaworks/redis/api/sync/RedisSetCommands.html#sadd-K-V...-
and
https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/d7aba13a8b65e66dedc01c51b73e3794cbe68a62/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/commands/BinaryJedisCommands.java#L139

### Question

What could be the reason for returning boxed primitives?
From what I understand boxing adds performance overhead.

Would it make sense for my library which uses Redis library, to keep and the return values boxed and propagate it to users of the library?

Edit: None of the methods return `null`, so encoding special meaning to null does not apply to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the main reason is to ability to retrieve an `Object` instead of a primitive type. E.g. it's possible to retrieve `null`.

Numeric wrappers like `Integer`, `Long`... are cached values between around `-128; +127`. All other values will be duplicated in memory. Moreover to store `Long` it takes over 3 times more space than store `long`.

**In general case I following following rule.**
If you do not need to return `null` you should prefer to return a primitive value than numeric wrapper.

Comment: As an aside: the upper cache limit can be controlled through system property `java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=...`

Comment: thank you. I guess caching of values could be the reason they consider it reasonable to use boxed primitives.
I forgot to add to my question that neither of the libraries return `null`. So encoding special meaning to `null` should not be the reason.

Answer (score 2):

Boxed primitives can be used in Collections whereas regular primitives can't (although they can still be added to a Collection of the corresponding boxed type), and also allow you to work with references instead of values, which saves time and space in some circumstances (i.e when the size of the reference is smaller than the size of the data). But as you say, boxed primitives incur the costs of memory and performance overhead.

Comment: Correct. I'll edit my answer to clarify that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: good points. I can see for long. double there might be an advantage when used with compressed oops. You have to pass around 32-bit values instead of 64-bit